# Java enter integer and output spaced digits and sum

Tags: java, string, loops, integer, converters

I'm a struggling newbie trying to finish a program assignment and am stuck with my output repeating itself with the digits of an integer that should be together on one line, but spaced (Correct Ex:The digits of 1234 are: 1 2 3 4). Here is an example of the incorrect output and below that is my program. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Enter an integer: 1234

The digits of 1234 are: 1

The digits of 1234 are: 2

The digits of 1234 are: 3

The digits of 1234 are: 4

The sum of the digits = 10

My program:

```
import java.util.*;                                                              

public class IntegertoIndividualtoSum                                                                                                 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)                                                         
   {

      long integer, digit, sum = 0;
      char digitAt;
      String Stringnum;

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
      integer = keyboard.nextLong();

      Stringnum = String.valueOf(Math.abs(integer));

      for (int count = 0; count < Stringnum.length(); count++)
      {
         digitAt = Stringnum.charAt(count);

         digit = Character.getNumericValue(digitAt);

         sum += digit;

         System.out.println("The digits of " + integer + " are: " + digit); 
      }
         System.out.println("The sum of the digits = " + sum);      
    }   
}
```

Comment: `should be together on one line, but spaced` What's preventing you from doing that?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I've been staring at my screen all day trying to figure that out.

Comment: Don't just stare at it, analyze it. How do you print a space? What does `println` do? Look into javadoc. Java is very well documented.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis hey thanks for the help, its been a long day...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Have to agree with SolomonSky here... Your attitude is uncalled for. Regardless of how simple we think the problem is, there's no need to be demeaning to others.

Comment: @JoshM My attitude? I pointed them in the right direction. They just didn't know where to look.

Comment: @JoshM hey thanks, but I must say my professor is much worse. You guys are awesome!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I must be misinterpreting then, heh. :P If that's the case, disregard my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the method `System.out.println`, which will print a new-line at the end. You can use `System.out.print`, which won't do that.

Also, remember that you get the part `"The digits of ... are: ..."` many times because it is *inside* the `for` loop.

```
System.out.print("The digits of " + integer + " are: ");

for (int count = 0; count < Stringnum.length(); count++) {
    // ...
    System.out.print(digit + " "); // add space
}

System.out.println("\nThe sum of the digits = " + sum); // note new-line character '\n'
```

**Note:**

- You can add a *new-line* character inside the `String` you want to print with `"\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that you're printing the entire line for each digit. You're looping across the length of the string, and printing your output on every iteration.

Your second problem is that `System.out.println` automatically appends a newline character to the end of the argument you pass in. If you use `System.out.print`, you'll get your output on one line as you expect it.

That should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If you do something inside a loop, it will happen each time you go through the loop.

Think about what you want to do once before entering the loop, what you want to do for each iteration of the loop, and once after completing the loop.

Also, be aware that you can call `print(...)` rather than `println(...)` to print without going to a new line at the end, and you can call `println()` with no arguments to go to a new line without printing anything.